# How to build an executable to run a html5 website, "like a mac widget"

Tags: javascript, html, widget, executable

Is possible to package a website to execute?
I need to send to a client unique one file to execute a html5 website, but i don't want to send him all the files and folders, and for this client i can't upload the site to a server to view it online. I want to send him just an executable where all the files must be read, and executed. The idea is to use this executable like a mac widget, but i need to send this to some people who don't use mac.
Thanks for answers

Comment: I found tide sdk, and i'm learning about, it looks a great way to do what i need. http://www.tidesdk.org/